# What's the rationale behind Hannah McKay's behaviour at end of Do the Wrong Thing?

Tags: character, dexter

Towards the end of Dexter Season 7, Episode 6 *'Do the Wrong Thing'*, Dexter makes a momentary decision not to kill Hannah McKay and instead cuts her free.

At this point, why would Hannah arise and feel attracted to Dexter (and make-out with him!)?

Shouldn't she instead have felt threatened by Dexter's actions? Shouldn't she have felt betrayed that he brought her over to the closed theme park as if to fulfill her long-desired wish but instead had an ulterior motive? Shouldn't she have pounced back at him the first chance she got, grabbing the same knife he would've used against her, back to his throat?

Answer (score 13):

Hannah made mention that deep down she's still the young girl that ran off with Wayne and based on revealed history, obviously likes the whole 'bad boy' type. And of course, she's still a killer, herself.

I think she finds a lot of similarities between Dexter and Wayne, so she's trying to return to what she sees as her glory days.

Comment: Any normal person would've jumped up and backed out of the table at being given the second chance to live, and most probably run away in fear or retaliated immediately. A killer on the other hand would've been furious and burned with the rage to retaliate, and would've done so on the first chance. Yes, Hannah obviously finds Dexter and Wayne similar, and likes the whole 'bad boy' type, but what she did may have been alright had she found that Dexter was a killer under normal circumstances, but not on her own death bed. Maybe it's Stockholm Syndrome. Maybe the next episode will reveal why.